# How do I print letters that fall within a range?

Tags: ruby, string

How do I print letters that fall within a range?

For example, if I have a word 'ruby', I want the letters to be printed one below another only if the letters fall within a range such as a - h.

Comment: What do you want to do with the other letters? Just ignore them?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use:

```
puts 'ruby'.scan(/[a-h]/)
# >> b
```

Or:

```
puts 'ruby'.chars.select{ |c| c[/[a-h]/] }
# >> b
```

[`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is great for picking out all matching patterns from a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ruby".chars.each do |x|
   if ('a'..'h').include?(x)
      print x
    end
end
```

Comment: This code doesn't work on Ruby 1.9+. `String#each` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, updated the code

Comment: Also, `puts x` ("printed one below another").

Comment: `each` is now either `each_char` or `each_byte`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ruby".each_char {|c| puts c if [*'a'..'h'].include? c}
```

Comment: Why `[*"a".."h"]` and not just `("a".."h")`?

Answer (score 1):

`puts 'ruby'.chars.select{|c| ('a'..'h').cover?(c)}.join("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

```
puts "rubyruby".chars.grep('a'..'h').join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing this, for example

```
'ruby'.tr("^a-h",'')
```

or

```
'ruby'.gsub(/[^a-h]/,'')
```

I would probably use gsub - I never quite remember which syntax `tr` understands

Comment: `tr` usually results in faster code because it maps directly to some C functions, which map closely to some assembly-language. It's not as smart but for speed it's the way to go. It only replaces characters though, not groups of characters. `sub` and `gsub` are a lot more flexible because they expect a regex pattern, but the regular expression engine comes at a cost. So, they're apples and oranges that have a little overlap as far as search/replace.